# Pandas: count occurrences that contains words and do not contain other words

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a count of the number of entries that contain some words but also must not contain other words. To be clear, I want to get an idea of the number of occurrences assuming an eliminating condition is not met. Here's what I have:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import re

 data = pd.read_csv('rando-file')

 vague_series = pd.DataFrame([(data['text'].str.contains('bla1|bla2', 
                                      flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex = True))

            &

           (~data['text'].str.contains('blah3|bla4', 
                                flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex = True))])

 vague_count = vague_series.columns[0].sum()

 print(vague_count)
```

Any attempt to count or sum has failed in this instance with an invalid syntax error. removing the columns[0] bit resulted simply in a 0, 1 designation in place of true and false.

Comment: Can you please update the question with more details about how it fails (e.g. the exact error message? That will assist in working out what is going wrong. From looking at the code, my first thought is that `vague_series.columns[0].sum()` should be replaced with `vague_series.sum()` to get the total count within the column

Answer (score 1):

Could you post data sample  for test ?

I try it with a custom sample and it working well:

```
import pandas as pd 
import re 

sr = pd.Series(['New_York', 'Lisbon', 'Tokyo', 'Paris', 'Munich']) 

idx = ['City 1', 'City 2', 'City 3', 'City 4', 'City 5'] 

sr.index = idx  
result = (sr.str.contains(pat='i[a-z]', regex=True)) & (~sr.str.contains('s[a-z]', regex=True))
print(result.sum())

>>>2
```

Maybe don't wrap it in `DataFrame` and try simply:

```
vague_series = (data['text'].str.contains('bla1|bla2', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True) & 
                ~data['text'].str.contains('blah3|bla4', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True))
count = vague_series.sum()
```

Comment: When I left it as sum in a df, I simply had the df returned in 0/1 instead of T/F. I unwrapped it from the df at first, but I received errors. (E.g. W/ vague_series.sum(), I got AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'. Then I tried vague_series.count(True),  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Then I tried bool with AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'bool'

Comment: it's because you have to unwrap the list too , just let parentheses, don't wrap it between hook , it will return a pandas Series, which have sum attribut.